# Oracle regular expression to pull rows from a table

Tags: sql, regex, database, oracle

I have to pull rows from a table where the column value contains anything else apart from alphabets, numbers, hyphen, underscore, space, and comma. It should not pull rows if it has only the above mentioned characters. Thanks for the help.

I was trying something regexp_like but 'm not getting the desired result.

```
REGEXP_LIKE(col, '[^[:alnum:]]|(^-)|(^,)|[^[:space:]]|(^_)')
```

For example:

```
TD-6 TTY-60X3APTNO DAY  => should not retrieve
TY-2YYTY 20TRH TY L/W   => Should retrieve
TIRREG CL3- HARDWARE &  => Should retrieve
```

Comment: The problem is that you're using regex alternation which is a logical `OR` ... it's the difference between using `NOT (a OR b)` and `(NOT a OR NOT b)`. See my answer below.

Comment: @david-faber Thanks a lot for the explanation, really appreciate your prompt reply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [Oracle's regex conventions](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_regexp.htm#CHDIEGEI):

```
REGEXP_LIKE(col, '[^[:alnum:] _,-]')
```

[Here's a SQLFilddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8543f/6)

The way the brackets work is that anything inside the bracket is matched, or if you lead the items in the bracket with a caret (^), anything EXCEPT what is in the brackets is matched.

Comment: thank you so much for explaining.Both your and the below users syntax worked perfect!!. really appreciate your time and effort for the SQL fiddle.

Comment: Keep in mind that `[:space:]` will match *all* whitespace, including tabs, newlines, and carriage returns. It's equivalent to the character class `\s`. It's also not a good idea to put a hyphen character `-` in the middle of a regex character class enclosed by square brackets. It's a good practice to put it at the end or at the beginning so the regex engine doesn't think it's part of a range.

Comment: @DavidFaber Good call on both counts, I'll update the answer and the fiddle.

Comment: @DavidFaber Cool! Nice to get some more insight

Answer (score 3):

You want everything that is *not* alphanumeric, or an underscore, or a comma, or a hyphen? Is that correct? Then you want something like this:

```
REGEXP_LIKE(col, '[^A-Za-z0-9_ ,-]')
```

Test:

```
WITH d1 AS (
    SELECT 'TD-6 TTY-60X3APTNO DAY' AS col FROM dual
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 'TY-2YYTY 20TRH TY L/W' FROM dual
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 'TIRREG CL3- HARDWARE &' FROM dual
)
SELECT col FROM d1
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(col, '[^A-Za-z0-9_ ,-]')
```

Returns:

```
TY-2YYTY 20TRH TY L/W
TIRREG CL3- HARDWARE &
```